# Tried adding an HDR in blender but seems that something is wrong..need help?

Tags: edit-mode

[image: ak hdr problem]

Tried adding an HDR in my recent project but it seems that there is a problem, need help

Comment: What is the problem? Can you describe what you expected? Have you tried observing your model in perspektive view (Numpad5)?

Comment: The problem is after doing everything correctly, I am not getting the expected result. I have added an HDR image to the world and all the settings are proper (as seen in the snap..) still the rendered view gives such a result. And yes I've tried every orthographic view !

Comment: Are your materials reflective enough? Did you try adding an object with chrome surface to see if HDRI is reflecting properly?

Comment: @MrBeep My problem just got solved, something was wrong with the extension. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are in Orthographic view. In order to have the HDR appears properly you need to be in Perspective view (Numpad-5) as said above. Maybe if you give more details one could help more. Also, have you tried F12 ? Is it the same result ?

Comment: I had some problem with the file extension and now its all resolved.